# how to insert kernel module which has only subsys_initcall

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to make changes to the md.c file and reload it to the kernel. Since its a kernel module I thought it would be an easy task.

But, after reading the code, I found out that it does not have a `module_init()`, but instead has a `subsys_initcall()`, and the `make` command does not create any `.ko` file for `md.c`.

How to load my new changed md.c (drivers/md/md.c) module into the running kernel

Comment: According to [drivers/md/Makefile](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.9.11/source/drivers/md/Makefile) `md.c` file is compiled as a part of `md-mod` module. For that you need to configure `CONFIG_BLK_DEV_MD` as `m`.

Comment: You need to rebuild entire kernel. @Tsyvarev, and how it will help for a) running kernel; b) file which is only can be built-in?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, okay, I got the b) case, but what about a)?

Comment: @0andriy: I mean that the `md.c` file can be compiled into the separate module when the kernel is configured with `CONFIG_BLK_DEV_MD`  as `m`. If this is already the case, then the module can be rebuilt and inserted into the kernel without the kernel's recompilation. Otherwise the kernel needs to be recompiled.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I am encountering some different results. I was able to built `md.c` by configuring `CONFIG_BLK_DEV_MD` as `m`, but inserting the module fails since there `md` is already there in the kernel.. and I am not able to find it as a module with `lsmod` hence not able to `rmmod` it..

Comment: You have rebuilt the whole kernel with the new option, haven't you? In that case, the kernel shouldn't have `md` module built-in.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks.. I was just rebuilding the `md` module and trying to insert it.. It works now.. Although I do have to `rmmod` and `insmod` all dependent modules like `raid*` and `linear`, etc.. A tad bit annoying..

Comment: @Tsyvarev Can you consolidate your comments and add an answer, so that I can accept it :)